# Automatically truncate TextView text so as not to overlap another TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a `ListView` that displays a bunch of homework assignments. The `ListView` items use a `FrameLayout` to position two `TextViews`. The first `TextView` is aligned to the left, and the second is aligned to the right. (Both are aligned in the center vertically.) The first displays a snippet of the assignment description, and the second displays the due date.

What I want to do is make it so that the due date takes up as much space as it needs and the description fills up the remaining space, like so:

|----------------------------------------------------|
| Read pgs 15-35, update tim... Fri, May 4|
|----------------------------------------------------|

Right now the description text will continue on to overlap the date. It will truncate at the end of the line though.

Is there anyway I can do this in XML, or do I have to do it in code by shortening the string before I set the `TextView` value (presumably in my `getView` call)? If I did it in code, I'd have to calculate the amount of horizontal space the strings would take up figure out how short the description needs to be. That seems like it could get messy...

Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a FrameLayout, this is the perfect place for a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in combination with ellipsize:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <TextView
    ...
    android:width="0dp"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:ellipsize="end" />

  <TextView
    ...
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or alternately

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <TextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/secondTV"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

  <TextView
    ...
    android:width="0dp"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/secondTV" 
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The RelativeLayout option did it for me! (FYI: layout_weight only applies to LinearLayouts)

Answer (score 12):

Try using the ellipsize attribute like :

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"/>
```

---

Note that Android, or at least some versions, require both the "ellipsize" and the "singleline" attributes in order for the system to actually do the truncation and add the ellipsis.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Didn't really work a intended until i specified the `singleLine` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Change the FrameLayout to a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

- LinearLayout: Make the due date width "wrap_content" and the description width 0dp, then add layout_weight="1" to the description
- RelativeLayout: Layout the due date first with width wrap_content, then layout the description with a rule that it should be to the left of the due date.

Answer (score 1):

Both Anton and JRaymond were pretty much on (JRaymond helped me figure it out with his example). This is what I came up with:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/due_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/due_date"
            android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(I needed to declare my due date label first so that I could reference it in the description. I also just realized that the android:ellipsize seems to be optional -- I guess it defaults to "end".)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ah, fixed it: I needed to set layout_width="0dp" on the Description TextView. (Yes, I realize now that's what JRaymond said to do...) Not sure why it worked before...